# I cannot upgrade nodejs in anyway

Tags: node.js, macos, upgrade

I can't update nodejs to the latest version in any way.

```sh
MacBook-Pro:claudiofiamingo$ node -v

v6.9.0

MacBook-Pro:claudiofiamingo$ sudo npm cache clean -f

Password: npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

MacBook-Pro:claudiofiamingo$ sudo npm install -g n

/Users/claudiofiamingo/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.0/bin/n -> /Users/claudiofiamingo/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.0/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n + n@4.1.0 updated 1 package in 0.514s

MacBook-Pro:claudiofiamingo$ sudo n stable

MacBook-Pro:claudiofiamingo$ node -v

v6.9.0
```

Why? The version of nodejs are the same: v6.9.0 !!!!

Comment: Try closing the terminal and open a new terminal (or just open a new terminal). Sometimes the problem is not node but the fact that some shells (especially bash) cache locations of executables so you won't see the update unless you start a new shell

Comment: @slebetman Thanks, but the result is the same. I also tried macOS installer from https://nodejs.org/it/download/, but the version remains the same :(

Comment: Are you using a node version manager? Do a `sudo n` and copy the list of versions?

Comment: @Intellidroid appear: node/7.8.0
    node/10.16.0
    node/12.6.0

Comment: what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

After you select `sudo n` you will have a list of versions (as per your comment), simply use your arrow keys to select/highlight the version you require and press `enter`.

Comment: I did it but the version remain the same:

Comment: node/10.16.0
MacBook-Pro:~ claudiofiamingo$ node -v
v6.9.0

Comment: Infact, when i try to run gekko, i get this error: ERROR: Your local version of Node.js is too old. You have v6.9.0 and you need atleast >=8.11.2

Comment: have a look at this it is a similar issue to yours...essentially you have two node installs (n [nvm] as well as and vanilla install) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x

Comment: unbelievable, I can't uninstall node in any way .. even canceling directories

Comment: Yes I prefer to use brew if I am going to install a local version of node (and not use a version manager). It is then pretty easy to uninstall. But I feel your pain

Comment: MacBook-Pro:home claudiofiamingo$ brew upgrade node
Warning: You are using macOS 10.11.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience, as you are running this old version.

Error: node not installed
MacBook-Pro:home claudiofiamingo$ node -v
v6.9.0

Comment: is there a reason you are using macOS 10.11?

Comment: If you look at the errors you are getting on brew install this might be the issue?

Comment: I updated the system but I can't update the node in any way .. it always remains the same version, I don't know what to do anymore, thanks all the same.

Comment: it is also impossible to remove it.